# How do I get *change* file time in Windows?

Tags: python, winapi, filesystems, ntfs

I am trying to use FreeNAS CIFS share with Windows (synchronizing files *from* Windows *to* FreeNAS) and hit a problem that robocopy.exe thinks that some files need to be copied again every time I run robocopy.exe (/COPY:DAT).

My favorite file management tool, Far Manager, tells me that "Change time" is different:

File times on Windows:
[image: On Windows]

File times on CIFS share backed by FreeNAS (ZFS):
[image: On CIFS share backed by FreeNAS (ZFS)]

I am perfectly fine with the fact that "change time" is lost, and I'd be happy to reset change time on the Windows drive, but I can't find how I can do that programmatically.

Python's os.stat(filename) returns st_atime, st_mtime and st_ctime, and, I've tested, this tuple has equal values between Windows and FreeNAS. Presumably "change time" isn't there.

Windows API also gives only 3 numbers (creation, last access and last write) but not "change time":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx

Apparently both robocopy.exe and Far Manager somehow get 4 values from the system. I'd really like to avoid disassembling them, hoping to get an answer here. How do I get and set "change time"?

Any solution will do (Python, C++, WinAPI, external command line tools that can manipulate that, etc).

Comment: Please do not tag bomb the site.  You should pick one language that you want to work with and ask a question about that in particular.  Otherwise, your question is too broad for SO.

Comment: Removed C++. Does it look better now? 
(If not, give me suggested list of tags).

I actually don't care in which language I get solution. From what I researched, there are no solutions for this problem in SO in any language.

Comment: If it helps [farmanager](https://code.google.com/p/farmanager/) is open source. You could probably just go and see how they're calculating the "change time" on windows.

Comment: cocarin: Good point, thanks! This somehow slipped off my attention. Will look at sources.

Comment: What's the difference between "last write time" and "change time" anyway?

Comment: Common convention is that last write is about changing file contents, and last change is about changing metadata (such as attributes). But you should confirm actual semantics for every OS + filesystem combination you're interested in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I seem to have figured it out, thanks to cocarin for pointing to Far sources.
Far uses NtQueryInformationFile to get times and NtSetInformationFile to set them, and FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION structure contains all 4 times, including change time.

QueryInformationFile docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567052(v=vs.85).aspx (ZwQueryInformationFile)

SetInformationFile docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567096(v=vs.85).aspx (ZwSetInformationFile)

FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545762(v=vs.85).aspx

```
typedef struct _FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION {
  LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;
  LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;
  LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;
  LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;        // <--- win!
  ULONG         FileAttributes;
} FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PFILE_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

Not sure if there are any nice wrappers for Python but this is good enough, I can write my own wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way than the accepted answer, without having to resort to native system `Zw*` calls on Windows Vista and higher (Server 2008 and higher).

Please take a look at the following sample code I whipped up to show how:

```
// Get a handle to the file whose change time you want
const WCHAR pathName[]=L"..."; // The name of the file
HANDLE hFile=::CreateFileW(
               pathName, 
               FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, // No need for GENERIC_READ
               FILE_SHARE_READ /* | FILE_SHARE_WRITE */,
               NULL, 
               OPEN_EXISTING,  // Fail if file does not exist
               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
               NULL);

// If file exists and can be read...
if (hFile!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  FILE_BASIC_INFO fileBasicInfo={};

  // Get the info we are after
  if (::GetFileInformationByHandleEx(
        hFile,
        FileBasicInfo,          // Info class from FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS enum
        &fileBasicInfo,         // Where to store the info
        sizeof(fileBasicInfo))  // Buffer size
  {
      // Use fileBasicInfo.ChangeTime for the file change time
      ...
  }

  ::CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Here are the corresponding MSDN entry links for your convenience:

- [GetFileInformationByHandleEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfileinformationbyhandleex)
- [FILE_BASIC_INFO structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-file_basic_info)
- [FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ne-minwinbase-file_info_by_handle_class)

Note: Also, take a look at the other information classes that are available with this *treasure trove* of a function for all your advanced file info needs. For example, the `FileStandardInfo` class gives you such useful tidbits as the amount of space actually allocated to the file (e.g., for sparse file actual physical space use), the number of links, is a delete pending, is it a directory, etc...