# Getting last change time in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I have two scripts, one in Python, one in Powershell, that get and compare the last modification of a file. The one in Powershell uses:

```
$t = $f.LastWriteTime.ToFileTimeUtc()
```

This time is primary for me and I need to get the same information in Python. I am using `os.stat` and convert the UNIX timestamp to 'Windows File Time'* using this formula:

```
statinfo = os.stat(file_name)
t = long(statinfo.st_mtime * 10000000L) + 11644473600L * 10000000L
```

However, I run into problems with rounding errors. `st_mtime` is a float and when I multiply it and cast to long, I am losing precision -- typically the error is less than 10 (i.e. less then 1 millisecond). I can of course fix my program so that it compares the numbers within this precision, but I would much rather have the same numbers.

There is a similar question on SO here: [How do I get *change* file time in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534448/how-do-i-get-change-file-time-in-windows) from which I gather I would have to access the structure FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545762(v=vs.85).aspx), however I am not sure how to do it without using IronPython, PyWin or similar Python extensions. Is there an easy way (maybe using `ctypes`) to access this information?

*A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for the benefit of anyone with this problem. Actually, it turns out that the question I mentioned, [How do I get *change* file time in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534448/how-do-i-get-change-file-time-in-windows), is a bit misleading, as it mentions an obscure driver access only function `ZwQueryInformationFile`, while there is plain `GetFileTime` function you can use. Either way, these functions require file handle and that in turn requires calling `CreateFile` and `CloseHandle` and for large number of files (about one million in my case) this is quite expensive. So in the end I used `GetFileAttributesExW` that only requires path. By my measurements this is still little bit slower (about 10%) than `os.stat`, which I think is down to the overhead of calling functions through `ctypes`.

So after some copy-pasting from Internet, I put together the following code that does exactly what I wanted.

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, byref
from ctypes.wintypes import LPWSTR, DWORD, FILETIME

class WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dwFileAttributes", DWORD),
                ("ftCreationTime", FILETIME),
                ("ftLastAccessTime", FILETIME),
                ("ftLastWriteTime", FILETIME),
                ("nFileSizeHigh", DWORD),
                ("nFileSizeLow", DWORD)]

filename = 'path and file name'

wfad = WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA()
GetFileExInfoStandard = 0
windll.kernel32.GetFileAttributesExW(LPWSTR(filename), GetFileExInfoStandard, byref(wfad))
lowtime = long(wfad.ftLastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime)
hightime = long(wfad.ftLastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime)
filetime = (hightime << 32) + lowtime
print filetime
```